# exclude array of entry types in query

Tags: entry-type, query

Here is my query:

```
{% set resources = craft.entries({
    section: 'resources',
    type: 'not caseStudyLanding'
    relatedTo: filterParams,
    orderBy: 'postDate desc'
}) %}
```

I would like to exclude two entry types (caseStudyLanding and webinarsLanding) but I have been struggling with the syntax.

Answer (score 2):

I found it here: https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/element-queries/entry-queries.html#parameters

```
        type: ['not', 'webinarsLanding', 'caseStudyLanding'],
```